# Why am I getting an error that I cannot concat two different datatypes even after casting the fields datatype

Tags: postgresql

I have a query in postgresql where I want to append a minus sign to the transactions.amount field when the transaction.type = 2 (which refers to withdrawals). I am trying to concat a minus sign and the transactions.amount field which is an int. I casted the transactions.amount field to a text/varchar but no matter what I still get the error, "PostgreSql Error: case types numeric and text cannot be matched"

Here is the query I am running,

```
SELECT CAST(CASE WHEN "IsVoided" IS TRUE THEN 0 
WHEN "Transactions"."TransactionType" = 2 
THEN CONCAT('-', CAST("Transactions"."Amount" AS TEXT))
ELSE "Transactions"."Amount" END AS Text) AS "TransAmount"
FROM "Transactions" 
LEFT JOIN "DepositSources" 
ON "Transactions"."DepositSourceId" = 
"DepositSources"."DepositSourceId" 
LEFT JOIN "WithdrawalSources" 
ON "Transactions"."WithdrawalSourceId" = 
"DepositSources"."DepositSourceId" 
WHERE "Transactions"."FundId" = 4 
AND "Transactions"."ReconciliationId" = 24
```

What's very perplexing is when i run the below query it works as expected,

> SELECT CONCAT('-', CAST("Transactions"."Amount" AS TEXT)) FROM
>   "Transactions"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*All* branches of a `CASE` expression need to have the same type.  In this case, you're stuck with making all branches text, because what follows `THEN` can only be text.  Try this version:

```
CASE WHEN IsVoided IS TRUE
     THEN '0' 
     WHEN Transactions.TransactionType = 2 
     THEN CONCAT('-', Transactions.Amount::text)
     ELSE Transactions.Amount::text END AS TransAmount
```

Note that it is unusual to be using the logic you have in a `CASE` expression.  Typically, you would just be checking the values of a single column, not multiple different columns.

**Edit:**

It appears that your call to `CONCAT` mainly serves to negative a value.  Here is one more simple way to do this:

```
CASE WHEN IsVoided IS TRUE
     THEN 0
     WHEN Transactions.TransactionType = 2 
     THEN -1.0 * Transactions.Amount
     ELSE Transactions.Amount END AS TransAmount
```

In this case, we can make the `CASE` expression just generate numeric output, which might be really what you are after.